# Is it possible to make my own network requests to a “smart” device without an API?

Tags: http, network-programming, iot

What I'm asking here may not be possible at all, due to my lack of knowledge with networks.

I want to start playing around with IOT objects in my house. I would love to be able to control various objects from the touch of a button on my phone.

I have bought a "smart" plug outlet which enables me to turn the power on or off via an app over my home WiFi, however I want to be able to build my own app and control the device exactly how I want to, just for fun.

This app I'm using at the moment comes with the outlet and as far as I can see, it was not meant to be customizable in any way.

My question is, is it possible to figure out the requests being made to and from the device, and create my own API to work with it?

I am a software developer day-to-day however my knowledge in networks is very basic. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no documented API you can, in theory,  to reverse engineer the API using sniffers. If you control the device from your phone you can install sniffers on the phone and see the incoming and outgoing requests. But the bigger problem for you is if there is some kind of security mechanism that the device and the app are implementing. The protocol can be encrypted so you wont be able to understand the network traffic or maybe some kind of key that will allow the device to get orders only from a specific app.
So my suggestion, if you are not experienced with this kind of work is to approach the device vendor and ask them for the API, some vendors would be happy to expose it if you would publish your code and let other customers to use it and expand their product.